# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j, propertyconfigurator

I have following jars in my project:

`antlr.jar
commons.collections-3.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
jboss-logging.3.1.0.cr2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar`

Code for the exception occurs:

`ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource("log4j.properties");
System.out.println(url);
PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);`

System.out.println(url) is as:

`file:/D:/me/HibernateProject/build/classes/log4j.properties`
and the file exists and browser can browse the file.

log4j.properties file with following contents:

http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-logging-by-log4j-using-properties-file

Exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator
    at com.pkm.commands.UpdateUser.doWork(UpdateUser.java:29)
    at com.pkm.commands.UpdateUser.main(UpdateUser.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 2 more
Java Result: 1`

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally seen if there is a problem with the classpath. Possibly the required jar is not present in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score -1):

You should config your java build path to make sure that the log4j.jar file in the order and export list!